# Heroku tables not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am building a news app with Rails. My tables in heroku are not updating when I run heroku run rake db:migrate. I have tried heroku restart several times. There are two items that show up in my local version, but when I check the heroku version, these two columns are consistently missing. I feel like I have read a million stack overflow pages on the topic and nothing has worked.

This is how I am committing my changes:

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "my changes"
3. git push heroku master
4. heroku run rake db:migrate

When I try to add a new post, I get this error in the heroku logs:

```
2016-10-25T20:23:05.717260+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-10-25T20:23:05.717163 #3]  INFO -- : [5f60f5aa-8453-4a3a-88f3-daf7b5c673d7] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms (ActiveRecord: 18.7ms)
2016-10-25T20:23:05.718597+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T20:23:05.718551 #3] FATAL -- : [5f60f5aa-8453-4a3a-88f3-daf7b5c673d7] NoMethodError (undefined method `slug' for #<Post:0x007fb471ff2cd8>):
2016-10-25T20:23:05.718481+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T20:23:05.718425 #3] FATAL -- : [5f60f5aa-8453-4a3a-88f3-daf7b5c673d7]   
2016-10-25T20:23:05.718644+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T20:23:05.718604 #3] FATAL -- : [5f60f5aa-8453-4a3a-88f3-daf7b5c673d7]   
2016-10-25T20:23:05.718727+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T20:23:05.718688 #3] FATAL -- : [5f60f5aa-8453-4a3a-88f3-daf7b5c673d7] app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:30:in `create'
2016-10-25T20:23:05.718686+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T20:23:05.718647 #3] FATAL -- : [5f60f5aa-8453-4a3a-88f3-daf7b5c673d7] app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
```

This is what I have in my local "posts" table:

```
Post(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, title: string, content: string, description: string, User_Id: integer, slug: string, photo_file_name: string, photo_content_type: string, photo_file_size: integer, photo_updated_at: datetime, ranking: string)
```

This is what I have in Heroku:

```
Post(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, title: string, content: string, description: string, user_id: integer)
```

Can someone please help? You would be my hero. This is stopping my entire day. Thanks!

It also might be worth mentioning that I created this app before and then deleted it. This is my second time deploying this same app to heroku under the same name. I'm uncertain if that is relevant.

Comment: Is the migration listed in the schema_migrations table?

Comment: yes, it is. Very, very confusing.

Comment: If you delete it, that migration should execute when you run the migration task.

Comment: Have you checked whether the migration ran successfully using heroku run rake db:migrate:status ????

Comment: So I ran heroku run rake db:migrate:status and got this. 

Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20161019224903  Create posts
  down    20161020160825  Add content to posts
  down    20161020161113  Add description to posts
  down    20161020161457  Add user id to posts
  down    20161020170105  Create friendly id slugs
  down    20161020170213  Add slug to posts
  down    20161020202402  Add attachment photo to posts
  down    20161024210723  Remove level from posts
  down    20161024220148  Add ranking to posts

Comment: It says that many of them didn't work. Posted oddly.

Comment: According to that migration status, only one migration ran successfully, which is the first one.

Comment: Also, according to the status, problem started in the "Add content to posts" migration and you should not even have that column on heroku...Check that  migration

Comment: Run this command heroku run rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20161020160825

Comment: I figured it out. I had sloppy migration files in my local version. I was asking heroku to delete a column that no longer existed and the whole migration failed. I deleted the leftover migration files in my local version and then ran the migration again. It worked after I cleaned things up. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command on heroku:

```
$ heroku run rake db:drop
$ heroku run rake db:create
$ heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

If this commands are not work, you can delete .git file from your project and add git again and push the project in heroku.